# Is System.Threading.Thread usage suggested for a Web Application method with .Net Framework 4.0 and WCF Services ?

Tags: .net, wcf-data-services

In our Web Application, We are using .Net Framework 4.0 with WCF Services. 
We have a WCF Service with some DB operations after which 
it generates a Report (Report Generation takes time). 
Here user does not need to wait until the report gets generated and hence we have thought 
of implementing  Threading  ( using System.Threading.Thread class and call this ReportGeneration in a new 
Thread from the main thread immediately after DB operations are over). 
Is it suggested to go ahead with Normal Threading or do we have a better approach ?

(Note :- We use .Net Framework 4.0 with WCF Services and WCF Service settings being set as InstanceContextMode = PerCall and ConcurrencyMode set to Single )

Please advise.

Comment: If a sync call would take that long, you have to support it anyway. Don't use background threads as it goes against the design.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest make use of call back available in WCF , that will help because threading is already there if you set proper mode in config for WCF.  [Push Data to the Client using WCF CallBack Service](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/wcf/721/push-data-wcf-callback-service)

Apart from that is rather than going with system.Threading i suggest make use of aync/await and Task parallel library available as nuget pkg for .net framewrok 4.0. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/

if you just want to use plain TPL do not use nuget pkg as its avialable in 4.0 framework, nuget is for using async/await.

Comment: We use MS VS 2010. So we can't approach as mentioned in https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/ .  Also we don't need a CallBack Service as our business scenario does not require a call back to the client.

Comment: @Narayanan - But you can make use of TPL available in .net framewrok 4.0 ..it is better than threading.